# What is the difference between GetActiveProcessorCount and GetMaximumProcessorCount?

Tags: windows, winapi

Windows 7 added the functions [GetActiveProcessorCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getactiveprocessorcount) and [GetMaximumProcessorCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getmaximumprocessorcount), but MSDN doesn't say much about them. As far as I can tell, both functions always return the same value, which is the number of logical CPUs in the specified processor group or the system as a whole. So what makes a processor "active" or "inactive"?

Comment: One's the maximum possible value, one's the actual value. Consumer versions of Windows are limited in the number of processors they support so these values could easily be the same if you have a modern CPU.

Comment: http://www.martincharvey.net/mch_custom_pages/Part%202/Ch9.html: "*Although 64 CPU's should be enough for anyone, [applications] requiring a great deal of compute resource may wish to know about processor groups in order to make use of the extra CPU's. Useful functions for this include: ... The OS has two sets of functions, because **for some some scalable systems, it may be possible to hot plug new CPU's into the system, without rebooting the machine**. This is intended for scalable systems which must operate continuously. It is then easy to write some code that discovers the group topology*"